# geom_density blind in terms of the aesthetics supplied?

Tags: r, ggplot2, aesthetics

I have to admit that it has been a while since I used ggplot, but this seems a bit silly. Either I am missing something fundamental when trying to make a density plot, or there is a bug in ggplot2 (v3.3.2)

```
test <- data.frame(Time=rnorm(100),Age=rnorm(100))
ggplot(test,aes(y=Time,x=Age)) + 
  geom_density(aes(y=Time,x=Age))
```

produces

> ggplot(test,aes(y=Time,x=Age)) +
>
> - geom_density(aes(y=Time,x=Age))
>   Error: geom_density requires the following missing aesthetics: y

how could the 'y' aesthetic be missing??

Comment: What's your desired result? If you'd like to plot a 2-dimensional density, you should use `geom_density_2d`.  Otherwise it's either a density over x OR y and you should specify only one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two cases when using `geom_density()`. It depends which stat layer you're specifying:

1. The standard case is the stat *density* which makes the geom_density() function compute its y values based on the frequency distribution of the given x values. In this case you must NOT proved a y aesthetic because those are computed behind the curtain.
2. Then there is a second case, which is yours, and which you have to specify explicitly by changing the stat to *identity*: This is needed if, for some reason, you've precalculated values which you want to feed directly into the density function.

Your problem arises, if you're mixing case 1) and 2). But I agree, the error message is not really clear, it could be mentioned to make sure that the used *stat* is the desired one.

```r
library(ggplot2)
test <- data.frame(time = rnorm(100), age = rnorm(100))
#if you want to use precalculated y values you have to change the used stat to identity:
ggplot(test) + 
  geom_density(aes(x = age, y = time), 
               stat = "identity")
```

[image]

```r
# compared to the case with the default value of stat: stat = "density"

ggplot(test) + 
  geom_density(aes(x = age))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-08-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Yes! I forgot that I had already the values I need to plot the curve, so stat="identity" was what I needed. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to plot the two variables in the graphic you need to "melt" it first.

```
test <- data.frame(Time=rnorm(100),Age=rnorm(100))
dt <- data.table(test)
dt_melt <- melt.data.table(dt)
ggplot(dt_melt,aes(x=value, fill=variable)) + geom_density(alpha=0.25)
```